# How to get / calculate statistics about voxceleb2?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, speaker-verfication

VoxCeleb2 contains ~1M utterances from ~6000 speakers (multilingual).

I want to get statistics about voxceleb2:

- number of utterances  & speakers for each language

I tried to find the metadata without any success.

How can I get (or calculate) those statistics  ?